# "illegal base64 data" when trying to base64 decode

Tags: go, base64

I tried to decode a valid (based on my understanding) base64 encoded string in Go with:

```
data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
if err != nil {
     ...
}
```

A full [example is here](https://play.golang.org/p/CvQtKW8qi6). I have a string `"eyJlbWFpbF9hZGRyZXNzIjoiIiwiZXhwIjoxNDQ3NzIzMzY4LCJmaXJzdG5hbWUiOiIiLCJpYXQiOjE0NDc0NjQxNjgsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly91ZGFjaXR5LmNvbSIsImtpZCI6ImE3ZTg5ZWQyMSIsImxhc3RuYW1lIjoiIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6IjEyMzQ1Njc4IiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJoYW5zb2xvQGhvdGguY29tIn0"`, which can be properly decoded for example [here](https://www.base64decode.org/)
or even in your browser's console with `atob(that_string);`, but for some reason go complains with:

`illegal base64 data at input byte 236`

Notice, that I can decode some other strings. So why can not I base64decode a valid encoded string in Go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your input does not have any [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding). Therefore, you should use [`base64.RawStdEncoding` over `base64.StdEncoding`](https://godoc.org/encoding/base64#pkg-variables):

```
data, err := base64.RawStdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
```

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/ZWfzYXQ5Ye